# CSS displaying differently on a live website than it did on Codecademy

Tags: html, css, distortion

I am experiencing a problem where I coded a website in Codecademys development tool. Once I finished I tried to upload it to my webhotel to see how it looked like in a live environment, but there seems to be some problems with the CSS stylesheet, as the elements are distorted.

Link to codebit: http://www.codecademy.com/codePlayer10717/codebits/gEe2CX/edit

Live Website: http://www.feelgoodadventures.no/

The code was copied and pasted from codecademy into the development tool at one.com and saved as UTF-8 for index.html and us-ascii for style.css

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a pixel value on line 54 of your css file - that seems to resolve it.

```
.imagelist p {
   padding-left: 80px;
   position: relative;
   top: -60px;
}
```

Also, within your html file (line 46) you have

```
<div class="Contact">
```

which should read :

```
<div class="contact">
```

CSS classes are case sensitive - there are a few errors similar to this throughout your html file, run it through a validator to catch errors or just go through it.